# set variable in angular without interrupting form post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need to use an asp.mvc form post. I use some angularjs on the client side. I know this question is not doing everything the "angular way".

What I need to do is set a variable `$scope.IsUploadingData` when the post happens so I can disable the buttons and show something to indicate progress. I have tried using `ng-click`, but it seems to stop the post from happening. Is there anyway to set the variable without interrupting the form post?

```
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost(Url.Action("Accept", "Members", new { area = "Testing" })))
{
other form stuff here

<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button ng-disabled="IsUploadingData == true" name="accept" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="IsUploadingData == true" name="reject" type="submit">Reject</button>
    <img ng-show="IsUploadingData" src="/SiteMedia/spinner[1].gif" />
</span>
}
```

Comment: Ok, so, you have an MVC form that does a non-ajax postback to your server, correct?

Comment: that is correct, I need the form to be allowed to post back to the server.

Comment: Right, so... when that submit event happens, anything you're doing in angular is going to stop, because the page is reloading. that can't really be prevented.

Comment: you are correct the page is going to reload, but in between I want to show a spinner and disable the buttons so the end users don't think something is wrong. The process can be slow for this operation.

Comment: Is just showing an overlay on the form submit event an option?

Comment: possibly, what is your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could use ng-submit to control the submission process and set $scope.IsUploadingData in the function you call from ng-submit. This is a decent write-up on ng-submit: http://learnwebtutorials.com/angularjs-tutorial-submitting-form-ng-submit

Comment: I like that idea and have explored it but I don't know how to handle the FormAntiForgeryPost tokens.

Comment: Actually this was the correct answer, and once i got the anti forgery stuff figured out it worked. ng-submit doesn't block the button's submit only if the form does not contain action, data-action, or x-action attributes.
https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit